# How to see my variables Objects

Tags: javascript

I'm new in javascript, i want to see all variables in my Object

I do this:

```
function configModal(data,buttonDatas){
...
alert(data.type);
...
}
```

but i have this:

> [object Object]

Thx

Comment: Add the code of how you call the configModal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `stringigy`,

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.type));
```

or display the object using console.log

```
console.log(data.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this [Firefox => ctrl + shift + k]

```
 console.log(data.type)
```

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

TRY [firebug](https://getfirebug.com) for firefox

https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel

**Google chrome**

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console